# Перебор коллекции состоящей из объектов других коллекций

Tags: c#, foreach

Создаю объект вида:

```
new Dictionary<string,object>
{ 
    {"obj1",List<myClass>},
    {"obj2",List<List<string>>}
};
```

Для класса `myClass` реализовал метод `ToList()`, в котором все нужные поля собираются в список строк. Теперь все это чудо нужно прогнать через 3 цикла для записи в Excel файл.

```
foreach (var someList in saveObjects.Values)
{
    foreach (var rowString in someList)
    {
        foreach (var row in rowString)
        {
            page.Cells[lastX, lastY] = row;
            lastX++;
        }
        lastX = 1;
        lastY++;
    }

    lastX = 1;
    lastY += 3;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Приветствую!

Перебор коллекции `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` осуществляется с помощью структуры `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`.

Для начала вам нужно определиться, что хранит в себе `object`, лежащий в `TValue`.
Для этого сначала делайте проверку `TValue` с помощью условия `if (obj1 is List<myClass>)` либо `if (obj1 is List<List<string>>)`.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in MyDictionary)
{
    List<List<string>> lst;
    if (kvp.Value is List<myClass>)
    {
        List<myClass> lstx = (List<myClass>)kvp.Value;
        // логика преобразования `myClass` в `List<List<string>>` (вызов Вашего `ToList()`)
    }

    if (kvp.Value is List<List<string>>)
        lst = (List<List<string>>)kvp.Value;


    foreach (List<string> innerLst in lst)
    {
        foreach (string value in innerlst)
        {
            //здесь логика записи в Excel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var lst` - работать не будет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо за поправку, скорректировал ответ.

Comment: Сейчас конечно стыдно стало, что такой вопрос задал, но накануне казалось неразрешимой проблемой. Такую конструкцию встречал, но еще не использовал. Благодарю за качественный пример.